# XDocument or XElement parsing of XML element containing namespaces

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, log4net

I am try to read the following string, captured from a log4net UdpAppender.

```
<log4net:event logger="TestingTransmitter.Program" 
               timestamp="2009-08-02T17:50:18.928+01:00" 
               level="ERROR" 
               thread="9" 
               domain="TestingTransmitter.vshost.exe" 
               username="domain\user">
    <log4net:message>Log entry 103</log4net:message>
    <log4net:properties>
        <log4net:data name="log4net:HostName" value="machine" />
    </log4net:properties>
</log4net:event>
```

When trying to XElement.Parse or XDocument.Parse the content, it throws an exception:

> 'log4net' is an undeclared namespace.
>   Line 1, position 2.

I know I can search and replace "log4net:" in the original string and remove it, allowing me to parse the XML successfully, but is there a better way?  This is the complete data captured (reformatted to allow reading), there are no xml namespace declarations made or removed..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First, create an instance of XmlNamespaceManager class, and add your namespaces to that, e.g.

```
    XmlNamespaceManager mngr = new XmlNamespaceManager( new NameTable() );
    mngr.AddNamespace( "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" );
    mngr.AddNamespace( "xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" );
```

To parse an XML string using those namespace mappings, call the following function, passing the instance of XmlNamespaceManager with the namespaces you've added to it:

```
/// <summary>Same as XElement.Parse(), but supports XML namespaces.</summary>
/// <param name="strXml">A String that contains XML.</param>
/// <param name="mngr">The XmlNamespaceManager to use for looking up namespace information.</param>
/// <returns>An XElement populated from the string that contains XML.</returns>
public static XElement ParseElement( string strXml, XmlNamespaceManager mngr )
{
    XmlParserContext parserContext = new XmlParserContext( null, mngr, null, XmlSpace.None );
    XmlTextReader txtReader = new XmlTextReader( strXml, XmlNodeType.Element, parserContext );
    return XElement.Load( txtReader );
}
```

Comment: -1 for using `new XmlTextReader()`, deprecated since .NET 2.0.

Comment: @JohnSaunders where did you see this? It doesn't look deprecated: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: FYI, you should not use `new XmlTextReader()` or `new XmlTextWriter()`. They have been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` or `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Comment: @JohnSaunders looks like your comment is deprecated, while XmlTextReader is not :-)

Comment: @georgiosd: "deprecated" may be too harsh a word, but see on the same page, "In the .NET Framework 2.0 release, the recommended practice is to create XmlReader instances using the XmlReader.Create method. This allows you to take full advantage of the new features introduced in this release. For more information, see Creating XML Readers."

Comment: @JohnSaunders I remember in ~2012 MSDN indeed said it's deprecated. Looks like they wisely decided to keep it.

Comment: @Soonts: I don't know. "deprecated" may have been _my_ term, to simplify the message. Certainly, now, if they added the word "deprecated", I would include a quote from the site in my message. There was no such quote in my message (the "FYI" comment I posted).

Comment: At any rate, I'm glad you've clarified because the original comment was misleading. Constructing `Xml*Reader` objects yourself is not recommended and may even be deprecated, but using `XmlReader.Create()` is a perfectly good practice, especially when you can't afford to load the whole thing in memory.

Answer (score 12):

You really only have two options:

1. Strip "log4net:" from the XML, as you suggested;
2. Modify the XML to declare the namespace, probably most easily accomplished by wrapping the fragment (via StringBuilder) in a root element that has the declaration.

Strictly speaking, your example is malformed XML -- it's no surprise XDocument / XElement won't parse it.

Answer (score -1):

you can use something like that:

```
<event xmlns="http://..." >
    <message xmlns="http://...">...</message>
</event>
```