# Linq to XML, how to acess an element in C#?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Here is my XML I need to parse:

```
 <root>
         <photo>/filesphoto.jpg</photo>
         <photo:mtime>12</photo:mtime>
         <text>some text</text>
 </root>
```

To access the `<text>` element I use this code:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml.Text);
doc.Descendants("text").FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

How can I access `<photo:mtime>`?

Comment: What happened when you tried it similar to text ?

Comment: System.Exception {System.Xml.XmlException}
{"The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name."}

Comment: just wondering , did `Parse` work for you then, i think it should fail ?

Comment: oops, that's why I can not access it, you're right, the 'Parse' is not fail, but there is no '<photo:mtime>12</photo:mtime>' in parsed xml. Any idea, how to solve it?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219419/xdocument-or-xelement-parsing-of-xml-element-containing-namespaces

Answer (score 2):

it is an illegal format of xml my friend
you cannot have a colon

Comment: Your answer does not match the question, perhaps it has been updated since?

Comment: as the xml is written it matches ColinE

Comment: What is a 'column'? there is nothing about columns in the specification of well-formed XML documents.

Comment: @ColineE "without a namepsace mapping, your XML document is invalid" : character is illegal without namespace and this is how the xml is given

Comment: aahhh ... you mean colon, not column. Now I understand. Thanks for the info.

Comment: hehehhe yea sorry about the confusion

Answer (score 2):

The element `mtime` is in the namespace that is mapped to `photo`. You can access it as follows:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml.Text);
XNamespace ns = "your nanespace URI goes here"
doc.Descendants(ns + "mtime").FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

However, without a namepsace mapping, your XML document is invalid. I would expect it to look like this:

```
 <root xmlns:photo="your nanespace URI goes here">
         <photo>/filesphoto.jpg</photo>
         <photo:mtime>12</photo:mtime>
         <text>some text</text>
 </root>
```

Comment: Ok, I need more help. My xml is not correct, how I can correct it? I have try to insert some string, but there another problem How to add ( " ) double quote character to a string?
 `xml.Text.Insert(5, " xmlns:photo=http://www.w3.org");`
I have also tried this solution [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219419/xdocument-or-xelement-parsing-of-xml-element-containing-namespaces, still, can't figure out.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here [How to Load and access data with Linq to XML from XML with namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743752/how-to-load-and-access-data-with-linq-to-xml-from-xml-with-namespaces)
Thanks for  [jmh_gr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/842685/jmh-gr) 
 Parsing xml fragments with namespaces into an XElement:

```
public static XElement parseWithNamespaces(String xml, String[] namespaces) {
    XmlNamespaceManager nameSpaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
    foreach (String ns in namespaces) { nameSpaceManager.AddNamespace(ns, ns); }
    return XElement.Load(new XmlTextReader(xml, XmlNodeType.Element, 
        new XmlParserContext(null, nameSpaceManager, null, XmlSpace.None)));
}
```

Using your exact input:

```
string xml = 
"<root>
    <photo>/filesphoto.jpg</photo>
    <photo:mtime>12</photo:mtime>
    <text>some text</text>
</root>";

XElement x = parseWithNamespaces(xml, new string[] { "photo" });
foreach (XElement e in x.Elements()) { 
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", e.Name, e.Value); 
}
Console.WriteLine(x.Element("{photo}mtime").Value);
```

Prints:

```
photo = /filesphoto.jpg
{photo}mtime = 12
text = some text
12
```