# How to Load and access data with Linq to XML from XML with namespaces

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

In my previous question here, I didn’t understand how to solve my problem.
[Linq to XML, how to acess an element in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739195/linq-to-xml-how-to-acess-an-element-in-c)
Here is my XML I need to parse:

```
<root>
         <photo>/filesphoto.jpg</photo>
         <photo:mtime>12</photo:mtime>
         <text>some text</text>
 </root>
```

To access the  element I use this code:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml.Text);
doc.Descendants("text").FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

How can I access ?
I have try http://aspnetgotyou.blogspot.com/2010/06/xdocument-or-xelement-with-xmlnamespace.html,
But it is ignored `<photo:mtime>` and I need to access it.
Please write some code.

Comment: if it's illegal xml you can't parse it with Linq to Xml - you have to fix your XML, also see the answers to your previous question

Comment: well the XML, isn't correct and that's why you unable to parse. If it's fine with you, I would suggest to open this xml file in VS and replace `photo:mtime>` with `photoMtime>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to @BrokenGlass' comments, your XML is not invalid. In fact the technique in the link you provided in your question (for loading namespaces) works fine. Maybe you just didn't change the example for your own needs. Here's a more compact generalization for parsing xml fragments *with namespaces* into an XElement:

```
public static XElement parseWithNamespaces(String xml, String[] namespaces) {
    XmlNamespaceManager nameSpaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
    foreach (String ns in namespaces) { nameSpaceManager.AddNamespace(ns, ns); }
    return XElement.Load(new XmlTextReader(xml, XmlNodeType.Element, 
        new XmlParserContext(null, nameSpaceManager, null, XmlSpace.None)));
}
```

Using your exact input:

```
string xml = 
@"<root>
    <photo>/filesphoto.jpg</photo>
    <photo:mtime>12</photo:mtime>
    <text>some text</text>
</root>";
XElement x = parseWithNamespaces(xml, new string[] { "photo" });
foreach (XElement e in x.Elements()) { 
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", e.Name, e.Value); 
}
Console.WriteLine(x.Element("{photo}mtime").Value);
```

Prints:

```
photo = /filesphoto.jpg
{photo}mtime = 12
text = some text
12
```

Comment: Why I get some times different xml result after applying your method?
1 `<{photo} mtime >12</{photo}mtime>`
2 `<mtime xmlns="photo">12</mtime>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (Your xml is changed a little, see )

```
 string xml = "<root><photo>/filesphoto.jpg</photo><photoMtime>12</photoMtime><text>some text</text></root>";
 var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
 string value = doc.Descendants("text").FirstOrDefault().Value;
 MessageBox.Show(value);
```