# Replace element in XML from a template

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I need to replace parts of a XSL stylesheet with custom processing instructions. The idea is to have a default stylesheet like that:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">
   <Placeholder />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The element `<Placeholder/>` should be replaced at runtime with a custom template, e.g. like:

```
var template = "<xsl:template match='/'>Today: <xsl:value-of select='Details/@date)'/>.</xsl:template>"
```

**What have I tried so far?**

The first approach was not to use an placeholder-element but to use string formatting having `{0}` instead of the element. But I am not able to use that option in my final solution although it works fine.

Instead I tried to create a `XElement` from the template and replace the placeholder-element:

```
var document = XDocument.Parse(/* above xml */);    // works fine
document.Root.Element("Placeholder").ReplaceWith(
    XElement.Parse(template)                        // causes XmlException
);
```

Unfortunately this results in an `System.Xml.XmlException`:

> 'xsl' is a undeclared prefix. Row 1, Position 2.

Is there a easy way to ship around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Specifically, your error message is caused because you're attempting to parse this XML:

```
<xsl:template match='/'>Today: <xsl:value-of select='Details/@date)'/>.</xsl:template>
```

This XML contains elements that have a namespace prefix - `xsl` - but you don't declare it. If you declare the namespace in your `template` variable you should be able to have it parsed correctly.

Try this:

```
var template = "<xsl:template xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' match='/'>Today: <xsl:value-of select='Details/@date)'/>.</xsl:template>";
```

I get this as the result when running your code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" match="/">Today: <xsl:value-of select="Details/@date)" />.</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Although a suitable solution I then tend to get the string representation of the document,replace the placeholder as @Dariusz suggests with string operations and XDocument.Parse() the result again.
Otherwise I would need to insert the namespace declaration into the template with string operations, because I get the template as-is.

Comment: My answer specifically explains your problem and gives you the reason why it's happening and the way to fix the issue with your code. If this is not actually what you wanted then why ask this specific question? Your question title is "Replace element in XML" - then you change your mind and want an answer using string replacement instead.

You wrote "The problem is parsing the xsl-Template that I get as a string." - this explains that problem.

Comment: Don't misunderstand me. As I said, you provided suitable solution and answer to the question. Thanks for that. 
I just mentioned that I get the xsl-template as a string. So I have two options, add the namespace to the string or replace the placeholder inside the XDocument's string representation as mentioned. Preferably I am looking for an option without any string manipulations...

Comment: String manipulations are much faster than XDocument, that is true, but at the expense of possibly generating invalid XML when replacing parts of the string (which I've done before and it drove me mad debugging!).

Answer (score 0):

Consider performing all replace operations on Strings instead, then parse the resulting document.

If you insist on doing it your way, make sure to add xsl prefix as a namespace `xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"` to your document, then it should get parsed properly.

Comment: As I wrote above. I am reduced to use `XDocument` here. The document itself has all necessary namespaces. The problem is parsing the xsl-Template that I get as a string.

Comment: You can easily add the namespace, prepend first > with space + the xmlns declaration. String operations aren't very expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Aaaah.... I found what I need. Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/3584742/5835794:

```
        XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
        ns.AddNamespace("xsl", "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform");
        XmlParserContext parserContext = new XmlParserContext(null, ns, null, XmlSpace.None);
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(template, XmlNodeType.Element, parserContext);
        var element = XElement.Load(reader);
        xsl.Root.Element("Placeholder").ReplaceWith(element);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying the document containing the stylesheet, the XSLT way of doing this is to add a customization layer. A customization layer is a stylesheet module that imports the main stylesheet and overrides one or more of its components.

Replace `<placeholder/>` in your stylesheet by

`<xsl:template name="placeholder"/>`

and then in your customization layer, do

```
<xsl:import href="base-stylesheet.xsl"/>
<xsl:template name="placeholder">
   ... custom logic goes here ...
</xsl:template>
```